# Cast part of Ctypes array into structure

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a big long ctypes array of about 500K uint_32s. I want a section from arr[0x4000] to arr[0x8000] to be referenced in a ctypes structure.

Basically:

```
class my_struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        (important_thing, c_uint32*128),
        (other_thing, c_uint32*16) #etc. etc.
    ]

#arr is a huge ctypes array of length 500K made up of uint_32
section1 = cast(addressof(arr[0x4000:0x8000]),POINTER(my_struct)
```

However, doing arr[a,b] turns it from a ctype array to a python list, and I therefore can't use addressof.

I'm doing it this way becuase I want to be able to do something like:

```
section1.important_thing = 0x12345
```

and for it to change the raw data in the list, but I don't know exactly how.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - **from_buffer**(*source[, offset]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer) is what you're looking for.

**Example**:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes
> >>>
> >>> class Struct0(ctypes.Structure):
> ...     _fields_ = [
> ...         ("important", ctypes.c_uint32 * 128),
> ...         ("other", ctypes.c_uint32 * 16),  # Other fields
> ...     ]
> ...
> >>>
> >>> arr = (ctypes.c_uint32 * 0x200)(*range(0x0200))  # Array filled with values [0 .. 511]
> >>> arr[0x0001], arr[0x0100], arr[0x01FF]
> (1, 256, 511)
> >>>
> >>> s0 = Struct0.from_buffer(arr, 0x0100 * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_uint32))  # Start from 257th element (index 256)
> >>>
> >>> s0.important[0x0000], s0.important[0x007F]  # Struct0.important first and last elements
> (256, 383)
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. Additionally, is there any way to get a subarray of a ctypes array (let's say first 80 elements) while keeping it as a ctypes array. arr[:80] doesn't work (turns it into a list) and I think getting a list and recasting to ctypes is ugly and memory-wasteful

Comment: Unfortunately, I don;t know how to do that in a nicer way. You could try wrapping the *ctypes* array in a *numpy* one (which allows slicing).